# 'AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException' occurred in AutoMapper.dll

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, automapper

```
 public class ClientViewModel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "The Client Code field is required.")]  
        public string ClientCode { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "The Company Legal Name field is required.")]  
        public string CompanyLegalName { get; set; }
        public string Notes { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string Zip { get; set; }
        public Nullable<DateTime> ScheduledDate { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> AmountDiscount { get; set; }
    }

    public class Client
    {
        public string ClientCode { get; set; }   
        public string CompanyLegalName { get; set; }
        public string Notes { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string Zip { get; set; }
        public Nullable<DateTime> ScheduledDate { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> AmountDiscount { get; set; }
    }
```

Edit:

> Exception Details: AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type
>   map configuration or unsupported mapping.
>
> Mapping types: Client -> ClientViewModel myapp.Models.Client ->
>   myapp.Models.ClientViewModel
>
> Destination path: ClientViewModel
>
> Source value: myapp.Models.Client

My `Client` & `ClientViewModel` has exact same number of props and below is my code that I'm using and its throwing error without getting much information, what I'm missing here?

```
Client client = context.Clients.Where(x => x.CustomerID == id).FirstOrDefault();
ClientViewModel clientViewModel = Mapper.Map<Client, ClientViewModel>(client);
```

> An exception of type 'AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException' occurred
>   in AutoMapper.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: Why are you using both `DateTime?` and `Nullable<DateTime>` when you can use only `DateTime?` ?

Comment: i have read some where that change from `Nullable` to `?` thats what i have done but nothing has changed and I put it back and now I have the exact same copy but still the same error

Comment: Also remember that `Client` class is generated so I have tried to change `?` on ClientViewModel but since I was getting the same error so I revert back the same as `Client`

Comment: Do you try without the attribute `[Required]` ? I tested it without and it worked great.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69978/discussion-between-aloisdg-and-abu-hamzah).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You just forgot to create your map. Add this to your code (before the call of the `Mapper` class) :

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Client, ClientViewModel>();
ClientViewModel cvm = Mapper.Map<Client, ClientViewModel>(client);
```

[Working demo on dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fSMiLR).

Answer (score 5):

Before calling Map. You need to call CreateMap:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Client, ClientViewModel>();
```

Generally you would call this in your application initialization code/class, in global.asax.cs for example.